# Different behavior in Visual Studio and app package

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crash, package

I developed an app using Visual Studio 2015 update 3.

When I run my app in VS, it works very well without crashes.  But when I create app package and install my app, it does not work as well as I run it in VS and crashes.

Why it works well in VS, but crashes in app package?